# Dual of a faithful representation

Tags: representation-theory

A representation $\sigma$ of a finite group G is said to be faithful if Ker$\sigma={1}$. Then is it true that dual of a faithful representation is also faithful?

Comment: Yes, at least in the finite-dimensional case. In the infinite-dimensional case it depends on choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is true. Suppose $G$ acts faithfully on a $k$-vector space $V$ (i.e. we have a homomorphisms $\sigma:G\to GL(V)$). Then, $G$ acts on the dual space $V^*=\mathrm{Hom}(V,k)$ by $$(g.\phi)(v)=\phi(g^{-1}v).$$
If $g.\phi=0$, then $\phi(g^{-1}v)=0$ for every $v\in V$. But, every $v\in V$ is of the form $gw$ for some $w\in V$, so $\phi(w)=0$ for every $w\in V$. It follows that $\phi=0$.

[Note that to prove that $\phi(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$ implies $\phi=0$ one chooses a basis $\{v_i\}$ for $V$ and writes $\phi=\sum_i \alpha_i v_i^*$ where $v_i^*(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$ is the coordinate function. Then, as $0=\phi(v_i)=\alpha_i$ for all $i$, $\phi=0$.]